# When printing newlist getting error as newlist is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def one(mylist):
    newlist=[]
    if len(mylist)>0:
        newlist.append(mylist[0])
    if len(mylist)>1:
        newlist.append(mylist[1])
    return newlist 

values = [35,40,50,38,20] 
print newlist
print one(newlist)
print newlist
```

Its a small program that I am trying to run on python but getting error as newlist is not defined when printing new list. Why?

Comment: newlist is defined inside the method and you're trying to access it outside of the method - should it be `print values` `print one(values)` `print values`?

Answer (score 0):

newlist array is defined inside the one function and its scope is limited to that function so it is inaccessible outside the function.

```
def one(mylist):
  newlist=[]
  if len(mylist)>0:
    newlist.append(mylist[0])
  if len(mylist)>1:
    newlist.append(mylist[1])
  return newlist 

values = [35,40,50,38,20] 
print one(values) #This will give the value of newlist returned from the 
#function
```

Or you can use:

```
newlist=one(values)
print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your codes look so complex, it can be done in this way to avoid of judging the len(mylist) and initializing of newlist:

```
def one(mylist):
    newlist = mylist[0:2]
    return newlist


values = [35, 40, 50, 38, 20]

print(one(values))
```

The code above could handle the case when values is empty [ ] or has only one element;